# Objeto no iterable en python y mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

estoy trabajando con tkinter y necesito enlazar una lista a un combobox. Los datos los intento sacar de una base de datos Mysql, pero al intentsar sacarlos, la consola me arroja:

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Y señala la variable lista.

Aquí dejo el código, lo copié de un tutorial en internet:

```
conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
user="root",
password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Camiones (Tipo text, Peso BIGINT, capacidad BIGINT)''')


query="SELECT distinct(Tipo) as Tipo FROM Camiones"
datos=cursor1.execute(query)
lista =[r for r, in datos]
        
        
conn.commit() 
conn.close()
```

La base de datos no esá vacía, tiene información.
Si alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal, por favor y muchas gracias.

Comment: En muchos modulos de bases de datos, no podés iterar sobre el cursor, y cursor.execute tampoco devuelve el cursor en si. Evidentemente en este caso cursor.execute devuelve None (que es lo que devuelve una función por default). En su lugar, usa cursor.fetchone() para obtener la primera fila de la consulta, o cursor.fetchall() para obtener todas las filas en una sola lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está mal el uso de mysql.connector. El método `mysql.execute()` no devuelve nada, por eso aparece `None`. Al ejecutar la consulta, se debe utilizar el **cursor** para extraer los datos:

```
# ...
query = "SELECT distinct(Tipo) as Tipo FROM Camiones"
cursor1.execute(query) # <-- Aquí estaba el error, esto no devuelve nada
result = cursor1.fetchall() # <-- Lista de tuplas con los registros
conn.close()
```

O también puedes usar [fetchone()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) para procesar fila por fila y así generar el resultado deseado de una sola vez.

Comment: Gracias aeportugal. Otra pregunta, la variable "result" sería lo que "lista" en mi codigo original?

Comment: @carlosarraez si, puede ser `lista` si usas `fetchall()`, ya que se devuelve una lista de listas (o sea una lista bidimensional) con todos los registros. Si usas `fetchone()` tendrás que usar un ciclo (`while` o `for`), tal como puse en el link, para ir recorriendo el objeto `result` que devolverá una fila por cada iteración.

Comment: Gracias portugal, ya lo había hecho pero apareció otro problema. Cuando declaro "result" como values de un combobox en tkinter, me arroja: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ljust'